# Rename a file if already exists -php file upload

Tags: php, file-upload, file-exists

i want to rename a uploaded file if already exist. i want to rename it into img1.jpg,img2.jpg if already exist. i tried many example but nothing suits for this code below:

```html
<?php
$valid_formats = array(
    "jpg",
    "png",
    "gif",
    "zip",
    "bmp",
    "pdf",
    "docx",
    "PDF",
    "xlxc"
);
$max_file_size = 3024;
$path          = "images/"; // Upload directory
$count         = 0;

if (isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $fname = $_FILES['attach']['name'];
    foreach ($_FILES['attach']['name'] as $f => $name) {
        if ($_FILES['attach']['error'][$f] == 4) {
            continue;
        }
        
        if ($_FILES['attach']['error'][$f] == 0) {
            if ($_FILES['attach']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                continue;
            }
            
            elseif (!in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats)) {
                $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                continue;
            }
            
            else {
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["attach"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path . $name))
                    $count++;
                
            }
        }
    }
    
}
?>
```

need some update for file exisits in the above code .

Comment: So what is your question exactly? We are not to fond of the "do my homework for me"-style question. Do you get any errors? What works and what does not? Your code snippet includes alot of validation etc, which could be omitted in your question aswelll.

Comment: use `file_exists` to check whether a file or directory exists

Comment: why you are using rename... please time like thing not overwrite the original one

Comment: @ Damien Overeem i tried eveything as i could...am not asking to do my homework

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
before moving the file to server put this check

$fname = $_FILES['attach']['name'];
if(file_exist($path))
{
    $file = explode($fname);    // explode file name and extension

    $rand = rand(1, 100);
    $fname = $file[0].'.'.$rand.$file[1];   // combine file name with some random value with extension
}

// Now fname will contain the original name or modifed name in it
// You can maintain a counter instead of random value that gives you 1,2,3 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing

```
else{  
    if(move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["attach"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name ))
    $count++; 

}
```

with

```
else {

    $targetfile = $path . $name;

    if( file_exists( $targetfile ) ){

        /* get filename & extension from target file */
        $filename=pathinfo( $targetfile, PATHINFO_FILENAME );
        $extension=pathinfo( $targetfile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );

        /* if the last character of the file's name is a digit, increment by one */
        $lastchar = intval( substr( $filename, strlen( $filename )-1 ) );

        if( $lastchar && !is_nan( $lastchar ) ) {
            /* Get the actual integer value from the end of the filename */
            preg_match( '@\d+$@', $filename, $matches );
            if( !empty( $matches ) ) $lastchar=$matches[0];

            /* Remove original number and replace with new incremented value */
            $filename = substr( $filename, 0, strlen( $filename ) - strlen( $lastchar ) ) . ( $lastchar + 1 );

        } else {
            /* last character was not a digit, add '1' to filename */
            $filename.='1';
        }

        /* determine new file's path */
        $targetfile = $path . $filename . '.' . $extension;

        clearstatcache();
    }

    if( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["attach"]["tmp_name"][$f], $targetfile ) ) $count++;
}
```

It should determine whether the file already exists in the designated target folder - if it does and has an integer as the last part to it's name it should increment that value by one and create a new filename. If there is no integer it should simply add '1' - but if the file does not exist it will use the original name.